# Django app : unit tests fails because of django.db.utils.IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, postgresql

On a Django 2.0 project, i have the following issue on my unit tests and I can't find the cause.

-- UPDATE : I am using Postgres 10.1. The problem doesn't occur when I switch to sqlite3

I am implementing a model which tracks any change on another model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Investment(models.Model):
     """the main model"""
     status = models.IntegerField()


class InvestmentStatusTrack(models.Model):
    """track every change of status on an investment"""
    investment = models.ForeignKey(Investment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name=_('modified on'), db_index=True
    )
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name=_('modified by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-modified_on', )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - {1}'.format(self.investment, self.status)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Investment)
def handle_status_track(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """add a new track every time the investment status change"""
    request = get_request()  # a way to get the current request
    modified_by = None
    if request and request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
        modified_by = request.user
    InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.create(
       investment=instance, status=instance.status, modified_on=datetime.now(), modified_by=modified_by
    )
```

Most of my unit test fails with the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 209, in __call__
    self._post_teardown()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 893, in _post_teardown
    self._fixture_teardown()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1041, in _fixture_teardown
    connections[db_name].check_constraints()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 235, in check_constraints
    self.cursor().execute('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE')
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "investments_investmentstatustrack" violates foreign key constraint "investments_investme_modified_by_id_3a12fb21_fk_auth_user"
DETAIL:  Key (modified_by_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

Any idea, how to fix this problem?

-- UPDATE : 2 unit test which shows the problem.

Both are successful when executed alone. It seems that the problem occurs on the unit test tearDown. The Foreign Key constraint fails at this moment because the User has already been deleted.

```
class TrackInvestmentStatusTest(ApiTestCase):

    def login(self, is_staff=False):
        password = "abc123"
        self.user = mommy.make(User, is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True)
        self.user.set_password(password)
        self.user.save()
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=password))

    def test_add_investment(self):
        """it should add a new investment and add a track"""
        self.login()

        url = reverse('investments:investments-list')

        data = {}

        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        self.assertEqual(1, Investment.objects.count())
        investment = Investment.objects.all()[0]
        self.assertEqual(investment.status, Investment.STATUS_IN_PROJECT)

        self.assertEqual(1, InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.count())
        track = InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.all()[0]
        self.assertEqual(track.status, investment.status)
        self.assertEqual(track.investment, investment)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_by, self.user)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_on.date(), date.today())

    def test_save_status(self):
        """it should modify the investment and add a track"""

        self.login()

        investment_status = Investment.STATUS_IN_PROJECT

        investment = mommy.make(Investment, asset=asset, status=investment_status)
        investment_id = investment.id

        self.assertEqual(1, InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.count())
        track = InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.all()[0]
        self.assertEqual(track.status, investment.status)
        self.assertEqual(track.investment, investment)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_by, None)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_on.date(), date.today())

        url = reverse('investments:investments-detail', args=[investment.id])

        data = {
            'status': Investment.STATUS_ACCEPTED
        }

        response = self.client.patch(url, data=data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

        self.assertEqual(1, Investment.objects.count())
        investment = Investment.objects.all()[0]
        self.assertEqual(investment.id, investment_id)
        self.assertEqual(investment.status, Investment.STATUS_ACCEPTED)

        self.assertEqual(2, InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.count())
        track = InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.all()[0]
        self.assertEqual(track.status, Investment.STATUS_ACCEPTED)
        self.assertEqual(track.investment, investment)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_by, self.user)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_on.date(), date.today())

        track = InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.all()[1]
        self.assertEqual(track.status, Investment.STATUS_IN_PROJECT)
        self.assertEqual(track.investment, investment)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_by, None)
        self.assertEqual(track.modified_on.date(), date.today())
```

Comment: Did you make all your Makemigrations/Migrates?

Comment: Yes, it is up to date with the model

Comment: Either i am blind, or your code seems to be fine.
Could you add one of your unit tests which throw this Traceback?

Comment: @Sativa I've updated my code with unit test.

Comment: The problem with some database drivers is that after an IntegrityError the connection stays in invalid state and every query after that will fail as well. You probably should issue a `transaction.rollback` in the tear-down step for the test just to be safe.

Comment: @PauloScardine Thanks for suggestion. I have the last version of psycopg2. Every test is successful when ran alone.

Comment: I was looking at the docs and Django's `TestCase` class wraps each test in a transaction and rolls back that transaction after each test, in order to provide test isolation. I dunno what `APITestCase` does but if you are using something like "SELECT FOR UPDATE" in your endpoint you may have to use [TransaciontTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase) instead.

Comment: APITestCase is a subclass of TestCase provided by django-rest-frameork

Comment: @PauloScardine I still have the error. Now it occurs when `self.connection.commit()`

Comment: The reason for the IntegrityError is that you don't have an user with `id == 1` in the database. Try to override the classmethod `setUpTestData` and make sure you have created a user with id 1 there.

Comment: @PauloScardine I think I have a user with `id == 1` but it is deleted when the test tearDown but kept in the "Track" table for a reason I don't understand

Comment: @luc, how are you getting the `request = get_request()` I am not able to get that to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I debugged through the tests and I found the issue happening here.

The middleware you use for capturing request doesn't work in `self.client.login`. Because it is never called. In your first test you call

```
response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
```

This calls the middleware and sets the thread request and the current user. But in your next test you have a

```
investment = mommy.make(Investment, status=investment_status)
```

This fires the `handle_status_track`, which then gets the older request that was leftover from your previous test and has the user with `id` as `1`. But the current user is with `id=2`, the `id=1` user was created and destroyed in test 1 itself.

So your middleware to trick and capture the request is basically the culprit here in this case.

**Edit-1**

The issue will only happen in Test and won't happen in production. One simple fix to avoid this is to create `set_user` method in the middleware

```
def set_user(user):
    current_request = get_request()

    if current_request:
        current_request.user = user
```

And then update your login method to below

```
def login(self, is_staff=False):
    password = "abc123"
    self.user = mommy.make(User, is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True)
    self.user.set_password(password)
    self.user.save()
    self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=password))
    set_user(self.user)
```

This will make sure each test gets the correct middleware.

**The wrong exception stack trace**

Your exception has below lin

```
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1041, in _fixture_teardown
    connections[db_name].check_constraints()
```

Now if you look at the code on that line

```
def _fixture_teardown(self):
    if not connections_support_transactions():
        return super()._fixture_teardown()
    try:
        for db_name in reversed(self._databases_names()):
            if self._should_check_constraints(connections[db_name]):
                connections[db_name].check_constraints()
    finally:
        self._rollback_atomics(self.atomics)
```

There is a try block, then how can an exception occur? One line 188 of `testcases.py`, you have

```
def __call__(self, result=None):
    """
    Wrapper around default __call__ method to perform common Django test
    set up. This means that user-defined Test Cases aren't required to
    include a call to super().setUp().
    """
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
    skipped = (
        getattr(self.__class__, "__unittest_skip__", False) or
        getattr(testMethod, "__unittest_skip__", False)
    )

    if not skipped:
        try:
            self._pre_setup()
        except Exception:
            result.addError(self, sys.exc_info())
            return
    super().__call__(result)
    if not skipped:
        try:
            self._post_teardown()
        except Exception:
            result.addError(self, sys.exc_info())
            return
```

The `result.addError(self, sys.exc_info())` captures the exception which was already handled by `self._post_teardown`, so you get the wrong trace. Not sure if it is a bug or a edge case, but that my analysis

Comment: you are absolutely right. I didn't think that the request middleware could be the root cause. Do you think is it just a unit test issue or can it happen also in the app?

Comment: I've fixed the middleware by clearing the request once it is processed. I think this was mainly a unit test issue but it could also be a problem in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by refactoring my code.

Now I don't create the track inside the `save` method of the investment or  inside a `post_save` signal handler, but in a method which is called explicitly

My code looks like:

**models.py**

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    """the main model"""
    status = models.IntegerField()

    def handle_status_track(self):
        """add a new track every time the investment status change"""
        request = get_request()  # a way to get the current request
        modified_by = None
        if request and request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
            modified_by = request.user
        InvestmentStatusTrack.objects.create(
            investment=self, status=self.status, modified_on=datetime.now(), modified_by=modified_by
        )


class InvestmentStatusTrack(models.Model):
    """track every change of status on an investment"""
    investment = models.ForeignKey(Investment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name=_('modified on'), db_index=True
    )
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name=_('modified by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-modified_on',)
```

**views.py**

```
class InvestmentViewSet(ViewSet):
    model = Investment
    serializer_class = InvestmentSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """save"""
        investment = serializer.save()
        investment.handle_status_track()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        """save"""
        investment = serializer.save()
        investment.handle_status_track()
```

The problem is that it doesn't do exactly the same : I need to handle the call to the method any time the object is saved. I am still wondering why the `post_save` signal causes this error.

Comment: Don't know if it's related but depending on how your setup you signals I had to put weak=False(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals) when running unittests to avoid them being garbage collected and causing weird problems.

Comment: @DanielBackman Thanks for this information. I didn't know this. I will check.

Comment: @DanielBackmanThanks for you suggestion. Unfortunately, putting `weak=False` when setting up the signal didn't solve the problem

Comment: @luc, I found the issue with your tests and its the use of `get_request` using the custom middleware which is polluting the system state

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by @Tarun Lalwani, the root cause of the problem is a bad management of the request middleware

Here is the fixed code for clarification:

```
from threading import current_thread

class RequestManager(object):
    """get django request from anywhere"""
    _shared = {}

    def __init__(self):
        """This is a Borg"""
        self.__dict__ = RequestManager._shared

    def _get_request_dict(self):
        """request dict"""
        if not hasattr(self, '_request'):
            self._request = {}  # pylint: disable=attribute-defined-outside-init
        return self._request

    def clean(self):
        """clean"""
        if hasattr(self, '_request'):
            del self._request

    def get_request(self):
        """return request"""
        _requests = self._get_request_dict()
        the_thread = current_thread()
        if the_thread not in _requests:
            return None
        return _requests[the_thread]

    def set_request(self, request):
        """set request"""
        _requests = self._get_request_dict()
        _requests[current_thread()] = request


class RequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Set the request
        RequestManager().set_request(request)

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # ---- THIS WAS THE MISSING PART -----
        # Clear the request
        RequestManager().set_request(None)
        # ------------------------------------

        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        """handle exceptions"""
        # clear request also in case of exception
        RequestManager().set_request(None)


def get_request():
    """get current request from anywhere"""
    return RequestManager().get_request()
```